# How to generalise an iteration in a mutliple list

Tags: pandas, list, iteration

I am a beginner in pyhton pandas. I am looking a way of generalizing an iteration in a multiple list. I have a list 448 elements(multiple list). So i need after 4 elements to group from element 5 to 13. after other 4 elements again to group for 18 to 28 and so one.
I am avoiding to have many condition under the for because my dataset is to big.
below is to code i am using:
########
**

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH_IN):
     for file in files:
         excel_data=pd.read_excel(os.path.join(PATH_IN,file),sheet_name=None,
 header=0, index_col=False, na_values=['DND','NAP'])
         concate_excel=pd.concat(excel_data, axis=1, sort=False)
         for (columnName, columnData) in concate_excel.iteritems():
             Values.append(columnData) 
 liste = [list(ele) for ele in Values]   for i, item in enumerate(liste):
     if i==3:
         wsh=list(chain(liste[i+1:i+13]))
     if i==19:
         wsh=list(chain(liste[i+1:i+13]))
     if i==35:
         wsh=list(chain(liste[i+1:i+13]))
```

**
and son on...

What i am trying to avoid is to have too many if. Can someone help me with a different way of doing it.

Comment: concrete sample data and an example of what you are trying to achieve will help contributors provide you solutions

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I am clarifying by giving sample data and an example. Let us assume my list is: liste=[[1,2], [2,3], [4,4], [6,7], [6,8], [1,4], [7,8], [9,8], [7,4]]   if n=0 merge([[2,3], [4,4]]) if n=3 merge([[6,8], [1,4]]) if n=6 merge([[9,8], [7,4]]). my dataset is 50 years then i will have to many if condition. This is what i am avoiding and looking a different way of getting result. Thanks your help